# ExtJS "create" or "init" component event listener

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

So any ExtJS component has the [`destroy`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-destroy) event to which attach listeners. What is the "inverse" of this event, i.e. an event that one can attach listeners to on component *creation* or *initialization*?

What did I try? I tried to hook into `initComponent` and `constructor` functions, but I'd rather have a solution that relies on event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Ext.Component do not have this events (render, show etc only).
But you can fire custom event in this methods:

```
...
initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.fireEvent('init', {...});
}
...
```

Comment: This seems to be missed unfortunately by a controller's control() or listen() in extjs 4.2.3